# Getting error ORA-01722 and ORA-06512 in the procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I am getting error while trying to run this procedure. I am passing 36 to p_nb_months and p_msg_per_loop is taking default value.

### Code is as below.

```
procedure prc_purge(p_nb_month IN number default 210, p_msg_per_loop IN number default 10000) as


TYPE selREC IS RECORD (

  EMAIL     desinscription.EMAIL%type,
  IDRA      desinscription.IDRA%type,
  D_DATE    desinscription.desinscription_date%type
  );

    type t_stringtab is table of selREC;
    tab_liste_tables t_stringtab;

  i number(10);      

    cursor c_table_order is
        select EMAIL,IDRA,desinscription_date from desinscription where desinscription_date < trunc(add_months(sysdate,-'||p_nb_month||'));

begin

    g_proc_name := 'PRC_PURGE';

    prc_log('Begining procedure');

    open c_table_order;
    fetch c_table_order bulk collect into tab_liste_tables;
    close c_table_order;

        for i in 1..tab_liste_tables.count Loop
        begin
            DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_action(action_name => 'Purging DESINCRIPTION and INSCRIPTION tables');
            execute immediate 'DELETE FROM DESINSCRIPTION WHERE EMAIL=:1 AND IRDA=:2' using tab_liste_tables(i).EMAIL,tab_liste_tables(i).IDRA;
            execute immediate 'DELETE FROM INSCRIPTION WHERE EMAIL=:1 AND IDRA=:2 AND INSCRIPTION_DATE < TRUNC(:3)' using tab_liste_tables(i).EMAIL,tab_liste_tables(i).IDRA,tab_liste_tables(i).D_DATE;
        exception when others then 
            prc_log('Error in procedure : '||chr(10)||DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK() || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE(),'ERROR');
            raise_application_error(-20000,'Erreur durant la purge ECOM. Consulter WRK_LOG pour plus d''information');
        end;
        end loop;

        commit;


    tab_liste_tables.delete;
    prc_log('End of procedure');

end prc_purge;
```

Comment: Post the complete error stack. It will have details about the line number. I see you have backtrace in exception, so I expect correct line number. Else, remove all exception blocks, and then try. You will get exact line number.

Answer (score 0):

Second argument of function add_month must be number data type, so just change your cursor from

```
    cursor c_table_order is
    select EMAIL,IDRA,desinscription_date from desinscription where desinscription_date < trunc(add_months(sysdate,-'||p_nb_month||'));
```

to

```
    cursor c_table_order is
    select EMAIL,IDRA,desinscription_date from desinscription where desinscription_date < trunc(add_months(sysdate,-p_nb_month));
```

Also you can define your table type without declaring record type, just try:

```
type t_stringtab is table of c_table_order%ROWTYPE;
```